# Como criar um botão que aumenta de forma crescente o valor de uma variável com Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Olá. Estou com problema para criar um botão com Tkinter que aumente (e diminua, quando for o caso) o valor de uma variável em uma *entry* de 1 em 1. Até o momento, o que consegui fazer não sobrescreve o valor passado. Ele soma com o último valor e concatena tudo.

Por exemplo: o valor começa em 0. Ao apertar no botão de "+" pela primeira vez, passa para 1. Até aí ok, porque sobrescreveu o valor anterior. Mas, ao apertar o botão de "+" pela segunda vez, ele soma 1 + 1 = 2 e concatena este resultado com o anterior: 21. Pela terceira vez, 1 + 2 = 3 e concatena: 321... E assim vai.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe como resolver? Vou deixar abaixo um trecho do meu código.

```
from tkinter import *

janela = Tk()

av1 = 0
entry_av1 = Entry(janela, width = 10)
entry_av1.pack()
entry_av1.place(x = 90, y = 50)

def somar_av1():
    global av1
    av1 = av1 + 1
    entry_av1.insert(0, int(av1))

botao_mais_av1 = Button(janela, text = '+', command = somar_av1)
botao_mais_av1.place(x = 40, y = 50)

janela.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Bom dia! Basta utilizar a função delete antes de chamar a função inserte, vai funcionar!

```
from tkinter import *

janela = Tk()

av1 = 0
entry_av1 = Entry(janela, width=10)
entry_av1.pack()
entry_av1.place(x=90, y=50)


def somar_av1():
    global av1
    av1 = av1 + 1
    entry_av1.delete(0, av1)
    entry_av1.insert(0, str(av1))


botao_mais_av1 = Button(janela, text='+', command=somar_av1)
botao_mais_av1.place(x=40, y=50)

janela.mainloop()
```